# Pushing cloudwatch logs to s3 with aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-nodejs

We are logging data to cloudwatch logs everyday. I would like to push this to S3 batch wise every hour/day.

Is there any existing lambda libs available in nodejs to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Logwatch
  Configure logwatch on logwatch.config (where you can configure mailTo &      mailFrom.

Run logwatch manually

sudo logwatch --detail high --mailto testmail@mailinator.com --service  all --range all

OR

Using Winston / winston-daily-rotate-file, a versatile logging library for Node.js